# How a parent process can ignore SIGINT and child process doesn't?

Tags: process, signals, fork, child-process, sigint

When I ran 'control c' in terminal (SIGINT). I want the parent process to ignore it, but no his child processes (that were created by fork() and execvp()).

I added

```
signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
```

to the parent process that ignore the SIGINT, but now his childs also ignores it.

Comment: Are you adding the call to `signal` before the `fork`, or after?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the

```
signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
```

after the fork() in order to distinguish the behavior of the parent and child processes.

Otherwise the child inherits the same behavior of the parent.

Comment: but it is in man 7 signal: A child created via fork(2) inherits a copy of its parent's signal dispositions. During an execve(2), the dispositions of handled signals are reset to the default; the dispositions of ignored signals are left unchanged 

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

why the child inherits the same behavior of the parent?

Comment: The child must have a different behavior, not the same. I wrote to add the signal handler after the fork to do not inherit the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Alez's answer will work, but here's another way: in the child processes, before calling `execvp`, run `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);`. This way will be helpful if you need to spawn more child processes after you start ignoring it.

Comment: but it is in man 7 signal: A child created via fork(2) inherits a copy of its parent's signal dispositions. During an execve(2), the dispositions of handled signals are reset to the default; the dispositions of ignored signals are left unchanged

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

why do I need `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);` before `execvp`?

Comment: @ElleryL Because we're talking about an ignored signal, not a handled signal.